# How to Refresh automatically Token uuid in Firebase and Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase in my Flutter app. So i need make Refresh Token automatically, without user Know.

I'm using provider in my Flutter for using Screen management. The `if user!= null` goes to the Home, `if user==null` go to the Login Screen.

When I make Search for Solution I read in Firebase auth that the uuid Token expires after an Hour.

So i need Refresh Token Before expired  How to make this?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    final user =Provider.of<User>(context);

          print(user);
           getToken();

       if (user!=null){
           print('token $token');

            return Home();


       }else{
        return login();
       }
  }
```

**this is regsiter function**

```
Future  regsiterwithemail(String email , String password )
async {
  try{
    AuthResult result =await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    FirebaseUser user =result.user;

 await DataBaseService(uid: user.uid,email: user.email,TitleNews:"").CreateDocumentInDataBase();

    return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
  }catch(e){

print(e.toString());
return null;

  }



}
```

**this login Function**

```
Future SigniWithEmail(String email ,String password)async {
  try{
AuthResult result=await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password:password);

FirebaseUser  user= result.user;
return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
  }
catch(e){

    print(e.toString());
    return null;


}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase automatically refreshes the (short-lived) ID token behind the scenes. You don't need to do anything for this to happen.

The user's UID won't change when the ID token changes. In fact, the ID token of a user will remain the same for as long as their account exists.

Comment: But After Some Time mabay on Hour  the  Screen go to the login  why make this

Comment: Do you understand what I want or not I need refrch Token Before expires

Comment: Again: the Firebase SDK refreshes the token automatically behind the scenes. I feel like this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and we're missing a lot if information on what is actually going on here. On what platform are you running this code? What does `_userFromFirebaseUser` do? What code does the redirect? And based on what condition?